# Issue with annotations for Primary Keys on Map<String, String>

Tags: hibernate, jpa, dictionary, primary-key

The following code generates a table where there is a constraint for the PK using the fields "Propriedade" and "doc_id".

I would like to know what is the most appropriate annotation that I can use to specify a PK?

```
 public class Documento {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
        private long id;
        private String numero;
        private TipoDeMidia midia;
        private String nomeDoArquivo;
        @ElementCollection
        @MapKeyColumn(name="propriedade")
    @Column(name="valor")
        @CollectionTable(name="DOCINFO",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="doc_id"))
        private Map<String,String> informacoesDoDocumento= new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Here is the SQL generated

```
CREATE TABLE docinfo
(
  doc_id bigint NOT NULL,
  valor character varying(255),
  propriedade character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT docinfo_pkey PRIMARY KEY (doc_id, propriedade),
  CONSTRAINT fk97c919c6e3b42d44 FOREIGN KEY (doc_id)
      REFERENCES documento (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. The PK is already defined: `(doc_id, propriedade)`.